# Cannot run .exe when under /home but can when under /mnt/c

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows Subsytem for Linux, I seem to be able to run a `.exe` file when I am under the `/mnt/c/...` file structure, but not when I am under `/home/...` file structure.  Is there a way to access `.exe` files while my pwd is under `/home/...`?

```
$ pwd
/mnt/c
$ "/c/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "print('hello')"
[1] "hello"
$ cd ~
# pwd
/home/mpettis
$ "/c/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "print('hello')"
(nothing run or returned)
```

If this is any clue for mounted file systems, here is my `df` output:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs         498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /
none           498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /dev
none           498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /run
none           498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /run/lock
none           498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /run/shm
none           498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /run/user
cgroup         498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /sys/fs/cgroup
C:             498799612 133929648 364869964  27% /c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `/etc/wsl.conf` and define the following inside it:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=11,case=off"
mountFsTab = false
crossDistro = true

[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true

[filesystem]
umask = 0022

[interop]
enabled = true
appendWindowsPath = true
```

The interop section explicitly enabling it to true might resolve the issue. Be sure to also keep in mind if you run WSL2 and also use the systemd hack, your Windows interop will break and no exe files will be able to be executed.

Comment: Thanks, this works!  Question though: there is some warning info, not sure what to make of it.  The actual command I used was: `"/c/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe"  -e "print('hello')"`, and I got it to execute, but in addition, I got the following in the return: `'\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\mpettis'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
[1] "hello"`

Comment: Yeah cmd doesn't support UNC paths. You'll need to use Powershell. Also you should only need the Rscript.exe part thanks to the `appendWindowsPath=true` . So long as R is in your Windows path, you should only need the exe. Lastly, I would also suggest `/mnt/c` instead of `/c/` unless you define a bind mount in `/etc/fstab` for `/c/` You can actually have both mapped (docker requires `/c/` so this is  quite common).